# Removing horizontal space in align environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  a &= b &+& c &+& d\\
  b &= b &+& c &+& d\\
  c &= b &+& c &+& d\\
  aoeu &= \mathrm{something long here}
\end{alignat*}
```

produces

[image: MWE]

How do I remove the space circled in red while keeping the "=" signs circled in green aligned? (Also, I want the "+" signs aligned.)

Comment: How should the "a", "b", "c", and "d" elements be aligned in their respective columns: left-aligned, centered, or right-aligned? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico left-aligned (so there's no space between the "+" and "c" of "+c" or between the "+" and "d" of "+d")

Comment: Thanks for this reply; I've adjusted the code in my answer accordingly.

Comment: You've actually applied the `&` separators here in the manner appropriate for the `array` environment, not `align`.  If you *do* want to use `align` in the future, you should read the documentation for the `amsmath` package (`texdoc ams;doc`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming that your real equation contains more thrilling entries than `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. If that's the case, you may be better off employing a flexible `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % automatic display-style math mode, left-aligned
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r} % automatic display-style math mode, right-aligned
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} % to emulate vert. spacing of 'align' env.
\begin{array}{RCLCLCLl} % the final column is a "dummy" column
  a &=& b &+& c &+& d\\
  b &=& b &+& c &+& d\\
  c &=& b &+& c &+& d\\
  aoeu &=& \multicolumn{6}{l}{\mbox{something long here}}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add the local setting `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` to better emulate `align*`.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for the suggestion. I took it on board right away. :-)

Comment: I tried using this code, and it got stuck in an infinite loop. I think there’s a typo in line 4, which should be `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}`.

Comment: @bradrn - Many thanks for contacting me and poiting out the problem. You're absolutely right, it should have been `l`, not `L`. I've fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Mico! Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 10):

As I don't know the real stuff that will be in your `alignat*` environment, I kept the three alignment columns. A solution consists in putting the r.h.s. of the last row in an `\rlap` command, which makes it have 0 width. In case this r.h.s. were  a maths formula, `mathtools` defines a `\mathrlap` command, which has the same effect in math mode:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  a &= b &{}+{}& c &{}+{}& d\\
  b &= b &{}+{}& c &{}+{}& d\\
  c &= b &{}+{}& c &{}+{}& d\\
  aoeu &= \rlap{something long here}\\
 a & =\mathrlap{\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you lose the \mathbin spacing of `+` with `&+&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh! yes. I didn't notice it as I focused on the extra spacing. I'll fix that in a moment. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: You lose the proper centering.

Comment: @egreg: That's right with the present code. With the real code, I don't know: either it may be unimportant (e.g. one wants to have only the significant part of the alignment centred, or it will be compensated by some formula.In each case, I think it's a matter of *lavorazione a mano*.